# Unknown PUSH_ACTION for ETPushService: com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush-android

Updated to version 4.8.5 and getting: when sending push message.

E/~!ETPushService: Unknown PUSH_ACTION for ETPushService: com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE
                                                                           ~!ETPush_ERROR:  ET PUSH SDK VERSION: 4.8.5 build 20620001
                                                                           ~!ETPush_ERROR:  APP VERSION: 6.06 : 606
                                                                           ~!ETPush_ERROR:  Debug version: true
                                                                           ~!ETPush_ERROR:  configureSdk() Initialized with: 
                                                                           ~!ETPush_ERROR:  Context: au.com.sbcommon.application.WHApp@1369466
                                                                           ~!ETPush_ERROR:  ET App Id: {et_app_id}
                                                                           ~!ETPush_ERROR:  Access Token: {access_token}
                                                                           ~!ETPush_ERROR:  GCM Sender ID: {gcm_sender_id}
                                                                           ~!ETPush_ERROR:  Analytics: false
                                                                           ~!ETPush_ERROR:  WAMA: false
                                                                           ~!ETPush_ERROR:  Location: false
                                                                           ~!ETPush_ERROR:  Proximity: false
                                                                           ~!ETPush_ERROR:  CloudPages: false
                                                                           ~!ETPush_ERROR:  GOOGLE PLAY SERVICES REQUIRED VERSION AVAILABLE: true
                                                                           ~!ETPush_ERROR:  GOOGLE PLAY SERVICES REQUIRED VERSION: 10084000

```
    <-- must be first in the list of services according to ET people -->
    <service
        android:name="com.exacttarget.etpushsdk.ETPushService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Comment: Same thing worked on 4.5.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Version 4.8.5 resolved the issue with Google's GCM Receiver.  You no longer have to manually declare the `ETPushService` in your manifest.  Please remove the manual declaration and allow the manifest merge to control the resulting manifest.

Comment: I was facing the same problem and this solution fixed the issue. I am now facing another problem that is every Push Notification that is sent is received twice on the mobile device. Did one of you already experienced that ?

Comment: Please update the question you posted with the requested information.  :)